# Selenium issues with IE tests

Tags: python, internet-explorer, ubuntu, selenium

When I change mt test browser to IE using the following line of code:

```
self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://www.mydomain.net/")
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception: Failed to start new browser session: java.lang.RuntimeException: SystemRoot apparently not set!
```

It works perfectly fine using firefox and Chrome. This is running on an Ubuntu server.

Comment: *SystemRoot* not set? That sounds so awesome.

Comment: Are you running the IE version using Wine or is IE being run in a Virtual Machine?

Comment: Did you get past this issue?  if so, how did you solve it?  what did you set system root to?

Answer (score 6):

How could the Selenium RC server (which is what I guess you are using) possibly start an **IE** instance on an **Ubuntu** machine?! IIRC all browser instances started by the Selenium RC server have to be *local* to the server. So if you want to test with IE, you have to run the SRC on a Windows box. Makes sense?!

Comment: Actually you can... http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-install-internet-explorer-on-linux.html

Comment: @Hannibal just because you can doesnt mean you should.

Comment: Sooooo true! :) I'm just sayin' :)